# Importing third-party javascript libraries in Rails 7 with Importmap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps, ammo.js

im currently working on an little project with three.js and i need some physics in my project.
Three wasent a problem i just did `bin/importmap pin three` and it worked just fine.
I am using the "new" stimulus controllers for this projct so i just had to `import * as THREE from "three"` and i could use it.
But now to my problem, i want to use ammo.js to create objects with physics, but everything that i try to get ammo.js working in my project, without an bundler, is not working.
I feel like that i miss something important, but i cant wrap my head around it.

I tried to use the Importmap like this `bin/importmap pin ammo.js` and it also pined somethings but when i try to import it like i did with three `import * as Ammo from "ammo.js"` i get this message from VS Code when i hover above the `"ammo.js"`:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'ammo.js'. '/Users/soerenklatt/Documents/Privat/Projects/Games/LightningStrike/node_modules/ammo.js/ammo.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/ammo.js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'ammo.js';`
```

Furthermore i tried to use the the `<%= javascript_include_tag 'ammo' %>`, i added an javascript folder under assets and downloaded the ammo.js file from github.
I than initialised ammo in my stimulus controller with this:

```
Ammo().then((AmmoLib) => {
    Ammo = AmmoLib;
  });
```

this also did not work so i did a yarn install, but at some point i was completely lost and out of my comfort zone. I am fairly new to Rails and especially to Rails 7 so thats why i need your help and hopefully we can finde a solution for me and everyone how has stumbled a cross the same problem.

In this manner thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your content of your `config/importmap.rb` file? Which URL does `ammo.js` pins to? If you want to do a quick check, try changing the pin to point to a CDN that have `ammo.js` built as an ES-Module.